# PHP to test Java class(about post data to web)

Tags: java, php

I wrote a program to send a String to Web URL, but before sending i need to test it use PHP on localhost. I never learn PHP. So would you guys help me out?

```
public class MessageSender {
    public static Boolean sendMsg(String outboundUrl,String message) {
        Boolean sendResult = false;
        URL url;
        HttpURLConnection connection = null;
        try {
            message = URLEncoder.encode("message", "UTF-8");
            //Create connection
            url = new URL(outboundUrl);
            connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", 
                                   "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", "" + 
                                       Integer.toString(message.getBytes().length));
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Language", "en-US");
            connection.setUseCaches (false);
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.setDoOutput(true);
            //Send request
            DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream (connection.getOutputStream ());
            wr.writeBytes (message);
            wr.flush ();
            //Get Response  
            InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
            String line;
            StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
            while((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                response.append(line);
                response.append('\r');
            }
            wr.close ();
            rd.close();
            String Whole=response.toString();
            //System.out.println(Whole);
            sendResult = true;
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return sendResult;
        }
        finally {
            if(connection != null) {
                connection.disconnect();
            }
        }
        return sendResult;
    }
}
```

I do not know what to do to test use PHP on localhost

Comment: So, You need to know if your own localhost can use php? Or do you mean an external host? Why would you need to know that?

Answer (score 0):

If you have installed php , make some folder ie /tmp/phppublic and place a index.php file there

[PHP Server](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php)

index.php

```
<?php
var_dump($_POST);
?>
```

Console

```
cd /tmp/phppublic 
php -S localhost:8000
```

To test your Java set

`outboundUrl = "http://localhost:8000/index.php"`

Comment: I tried <?php 
print_r($_POST); 
?>  I can print in eclipse, but on browser is shows Array();

Comment: Use var_dump as $_POST is array so you have data nicely dumped, also in your Java ucomment  //System.out.println(Whole); , you cant acces it directly form a browser $_POST variable will be empty as you are not sending anything, using your Java you are actually sending a POST request , so just see what Whole will show in eclipse

Comment: thanks very much! but if i want to see it on my browser, what should i do?

Comment: you could use $_GET['someparamname']; so hit `http://localhost:8000/index.php?message=somemessagehere` and change php `echo $_GET['message'];` Also it would be helpful if you can explain what exactly you need to test. If you need a POST to work you will need to have HTML part in index.php that shows a POST form that has input element for message and submit it to same index.php , I hope you know HMTL ;)

Comment: the var message is content of XML. And i want to post it on the URL.  Thanks man!!!